# How do I refactor this block of code to make it dry

Tags: ruby, class, methods, controller, dry

How do I go about making this code block dry?
I understand that dry means dont repeat yourself but I don't see any obvious opportunity for refactoring.

Index, show, edit, and create seem like basic/necessary methods. They appear to be pretty dry to me.

The methods after I am not sure about.

I haven't tried anything other than googling so far.

```rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

    Slack.notify_channel 
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

    Slack.notify_channel
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end

    Slack.notify_channel
  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email)
    end
end
```

There is no rails backend attached to this code snippet. I am assuming it is just theoretical - wanting us to refactor the code to make it shorter.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Seems pretty DRY to me too ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. `create` and `update` are pretty similar, but I think it'd be a bit premature and obfuscative to dump them into a helper with tons of params and a tiny body. I'd say head to Code Review but [you have to be the author of the code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for that to work.

Comment: I appreciate the response @ggorlen. I will run it by my TA tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you can do something like that.

```rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include ExceptionHandling
  before_action :load_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  after_action :slack_notify_channel, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.create!(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
    end
  end

  def update
    @user.update!(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user.destroy!
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

  def load_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def slack_notify_channel
    Slack.notify_channel
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email)
  end
end
```

I would recommend you to create a concern to manage exceptions and render each specific error by exception. Then you can avoid having two ways in each action to render a good and bad case.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will see if I can do something similar to what you suggested. @mariotux

Answer (score 0):

I have to guess a bit about what's in your `ApplicationController` and `User` classes. But the obviously repeated code is `@user = User.find(params[:id])`. Your `show` and `edit` methods both just run this line. So, they do exactly the same thing, which they oughtn't to do. One method for one thing.

Also, once you resolve `show` and `edit` into a single method, your `create`, `update` and `destroy` methods should call it instead of repeating the line.

Next, I wouldn't use `new` as a method name, since it is already used by `BasicObject::new`. I tested a few things and it gets pretty unclear:

```
class Test
  attr_reader :test
  def initialize
    @test = 'test'
  end
end

class Test2
  attr_reader :test2
  def new
    p 'test2new'
    @test2 = Test.new
  end
end

testx = Test2.new
p testx.new.test
p testx.test2.test

=> "test2new"
=> "test"
=> "test"
```

It takes extra effort to see when you're calling your own `new` method and when you're calling `BasicObject::new`. So, I'd change that to `new_user` or something, if you even need it at all — I don't see why you need both it and your `create` method. (If you don't need it, get rid of it.)

Finally, `@user = User.find(params[:id])` doesn't imply either showing or editing, so understanding what you're trying to do and coming up with a name that reflects it (e.g. `set_user_id`) is something that ought to be done as well.

Comment: Thanks @BobRhodes. I am going to try to implement some of your suggestions.